# How can i hide or disappear an element in XNA?

Tags: c#, xna

I want to show or hide an element when it touches another.

```
if (player.rectangle.isOnTopOf(object.rectangle))
{
      //Here I have to put the code
}
```

`isOnTopOf()` is a function which detects the collision between the rectangles.

Comment: If you want to detect an intersection between rectangles you can use the Rectangle.Intersect method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to make it non visible, just ignore it in your `Draw(GameTime gameTime)` method

```
if (!player.rectangle.isOnTopOf(object.rectangle))
{
     //If not touching, draw
     player.Draw(); //Or whatever
}
```

If you want to go further, add an `IsVisible` property to your player class (`public bool IsVisible`) and update it in your `Update(GameTime gameTime)` method like so:

```
player.IsVisible = player.rectangle.isOnTopOf(object.rectangle)
```